# Why do very few questions tagged stochastic PDE actually have stochastic PDE in them?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

I check the tag [stochastic-pde](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stochastic-pde) occasionally and always like 9 out of the last 10 posts have no stochastic PDE in them. I comment and suggest an edit to remove the tag. The tag has the following warning:

> Please do not use this tag just because there are stochastic processes and differential equations in your question. Consider if [tag: SDE] is a better choice. This tag is only to be used for PDEs driven by noise.

But still there are several questions that involve things like Fokker-Planck equations, or stochastic ODE, or just vaguely things involving calculus and stochastic processes. I originally posted in the tag management thread but I was informed by a kind commenter that it might be better to make a new thread, because I am not quite sure what to do.

I like stochastic PDEs so I like the tag. But most of the questions do not fit the tag, even with the disclaimer included in the description.

How do we encourage proper use of this tag?

Comment: A good question! I don't want to go off on a tangent, but this is unfortunately not limited to this tag ([tag:number-theory] and [tag:set-theory] are often abused as well). I think we should encourage more users to read the tag wikis but idk how to do so...

Comment: @Integrand As discussed quite recently, a different between number-theory and set-theory is quite big - because there are user who carefully follow both set-theory and elementary-set-theory and if some questions are, they retag them. You can check who are the users who most frequently [add](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1146497/number-of-tag-additions-per-user?tagname=set-theory) or [remove](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1038477/number-of-tag-removals-per-user?tagname=set-theory) set-theory and which users ...

Comment: ... often [add](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1146497/number-of-tag-additions-per-user?tagname=elementary-set-theory) and [remove](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1038477/number-of-tag-removals-per-user?tagname=elementary-set-theory) elementary-set-theory. (Removals are probably more relevant if we're looking at sets related to cleaning up tags.)

Comment: +1 For bringing this up. Unfortunately, this is an area I know nothing bout - so I won't be of much help. Let us hope that some users with knowledge of this are will joint the disucssion.

Comment: I think I understand your frustration - you have several legitimate tag edits rejected... I fixed some of them, but like Martin I can only edit those that I am sure it's just SODE but not SPDE.

Comment: One thing I'd like to point out is that you should not flood the suggested edit queue with retag suggestions, which if all accepted, would flood the main site with edited questions.  So please pace yourself when suggesting only the deletion of a tag.

Comment: @amWhy Sure. It limited me to 5 anyway.

Comment: Just don't suggest five such edits in three minutes or so.

Comment: I used to be confused by this distinction because PDE/SDE are naturally dual to each other (PDEs as generators of Markov processes/diffusions for example) so one might lump them together as stochastic-pde

Comment: Maybe they are not aware its stochastic PDE